# How to orient the undirected edges in the CPDAGs learned by some Bayesian Network structure learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

Some Bayesian Network (BN) structure learning algorithms (such as the PC algorithm) learns a CPDAG as the output, which contains both directed and undirected edges. One common evaluation metric for BN learning is Hamming distance `H(G) = A(G) + D(G) + I(G)`, which consists of the number of added edges `A(G)`, deleted edges `D(G)`, and inverted edges `I(G)` of the learned network `G` with respect to the original network `G0`. So if I want to use this metric to evaluate one algorithm that outputs a CPDAG (such as the PC algorithm), I think I have to orient the undirected edges in the CPDAG to make the calculation of the Hamming distance feasible. But I did not find some details to do this in the literature. Maybe just randomly choose a direction for the undirected edges?

Comment: Well I have got the answer...

Answer (score 0):

From a personal experience, I started with a random direction of each undirected arc and then measured the arc strength using the arc.strength() function. Finally, I compared the score with the score of the opposite direction. The higher negative values are better. Note that when the direction is changed not only the score of that arc changes but also the score of other arcs might change. In this case you have two options, either compare the average score of all arcs or only the arc that you are interested in. In some cases you might end up with a graph that contains cycles. In this situation you are forced to choose the other direction.